# Retrieve values in nested link with C#

Tags: c#

I have a nested string list and I am trying to save each item in specific variable.
I tried this way but I got this result with duplication of each one:

- one one
- Two Two Two Two Two Two Two
- three three three three three three three
- four four four four four four four
- five five  five five five five five
- six six six six six six six
- seven seven seven seven seven seven

  ```
       string argp;
       string arg0;
       string arg1;
       string arg2;
       string arg3;
       string arg4;
       string arg5;
       string arg6;
       string arguments;
       List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>();
       myList.Add(new List<string> { @"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" });

       myList.Add(new List<string> { @"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" });

       for (var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
       {


           argp = myList[i][0];
           for (var j = 0; j < myList[i].Count; j++)
           {

               arg0 = myList[i][j];
               // = "localhost";
               arg1 = myList[i][j];
               arg2 = myList[i][j];
               arg3 = myList[i][j];
               arg4 = myList[i][j];
               arg5 = myList[i][j];
               arg6 = myList[i][j];
               arguments = myList[i][j] + " " + myList[i][j] + " " + arg2 + " " + arg3 + " " + arg4 + " " + arg5 + " " + arg6;
               Console.WriteLine(arguments);


           }
           Console.WriteLine("==============");
       }
  ```

Comment: `argX = myList[i][j];` `i` and `j` will be the same for all `X`es.

Comment: You don't need the inner loop, as you're assigning all variables at once anyway. Just omit the inner loop and move the code within that loop into the outer loop.

Comment: But you're overwriting the results on every iteration of the outer loop, so `arg0` will only have the value of `List[1][0]` for instance.

Comment: it is a nested list so I have many lists inside an initial one

Comment: It is not really clear what the goal is. What would your expected output be?

Comment: also, if you find yourself declaring arg0, arg1... argn, you might consider using a list or some other collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the inner loop:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    var list = myList[i]; // todo - check if enough elements?
    arg0 = list[0];
    arg1 = list[1];
    arg2 = list[2];
    arg3 = list[3];
    arg4 = list[4];
    arg5 = list[5];
    arg6 = list[6];

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arg0, arg1, ...)); 
    Console.WriteLine("==============");
}
```

Note that this will overwrite `argX`'s in every iteration, if the goal is to combine arguments positionally you can do something like `arg0 += " " + list[0];` (as a quick and dirty approach, if a lot of lists are expected then better to consider using something like [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder)).

If the goal is to just output the arguments you can do it much easier with `foreach` and `string.Join`:

```cs
foreach (var list in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list));
    Console.WriteLine("==============");
}
```